# How to refresh table view without any jerk just like Pinterest app in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am fetching data from server using rest service. When I get all data then I refresh table view. I am fetching by page by page just like in Pinterest app has when table view reach at last row using scroll then it fetch data for next pages. But if you look at Pinterest app that is very smooth and there is no jerk (may be they use scroll instead of table) but in my app it shows jerk when fetched data for next pages.

I am using very ordinary approach get data and reload table `[myTable reloadData]`, so thats why not adding code in this question. So kindly suggest me better approach to make this smooth. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that they are using a UICollectionView with a custom flowLayout. Not a UITableView

Answer (score 1):

You could try simply adding the new rows to the table view:

```
insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
```

E.g.:

```
NSMutableArray* indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
for (short i = X; i < X + N; ++i)
    [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];

[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
```

As you can see, I am just adding the new indexPaths to the table (I am assuming just one section).

This will force the table view to refresh its content by displaying the new rows -- keep in mind that your datasource delegate must be able to provide the data for the new rows, otherwise the app will crash.